# How to make query in Apollo-Client?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Using REST-API, we can make fetch query than make query to server.
I use "Apollo-client", but I want to create query witout connecting this query to component. Can I do it?
May be I should use methods client.query (http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ApolloClient.query) and client.mutate or something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({uri: 'http://localhost:3003/graphql'})
});;

const loginQueruy = gql `Your query code here`,
```

and then in code

```
const apolloQuery = {
        query: loginQuery,
    };
apolloClient
        .query(apolloQuery)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("RES", res)
        })
```